# How to make a "normal" cup of coffee with instant coffee

Tags: instant, chemistry

I drink freeze dried instant coffee usually and when I have it I find that it is much stronger than regular brewed coffee. I figure that im putting too much powder in.

This got me thinking, if one was to reduce the coffee in ones cup down to a powder how much of that powder would be there? This is asked to figure out "how much coffee is in my cup?".

Comment: Well, that’s a tricky question. There is no average cup of coffee, even if you compare just pour-over, or rather, there’s a wide range between the often cited 60g per liter and what is actually used. There’s also a certain cultural difference, the US being infamous for rather weak brews (outside the espresso-based coffee shop drinks). I am sure you already realized that if your instant coffee is too strong, you could simply use a bit less next time, until you get the desired strength (or weakness).